# Download Data from Data Extension using Python FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

***Requirement:***
I was looking into the **sample_dataextension.py** and try to download list of data extensions and corresponding data extensions columns and rows.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/objsamples/sample_dataextension.py

Step 1: I can extract the list of Data Extension by passing the credentials and below is the sample data extension values.

[image]
[image]

Step 2: Using the below code i was not able to fetch any columns

[image]

NameofDE: customerKey/Name of DE

I got the below result with empty result set.

[image]

**Issue:** 
I am not sure what I have missed or if I did something wrong in the code to make it work.  If you can help me to resolve this would be great. I need to pass a DE and get the corresponding Columns and Rows to download as a file. Once i get this sorted i can work on to download other DE.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get columns

> response_column = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Column()
> response_column.auth_stub = myClient
> response_column.CustomerKey = customer_key
> response_column = response_column.get()
> print(response_column.results)